# How to upload file on server with file name which is given from client side

Tags: php

I am uploading file from iphone to sever using php code but when upload it gives random number name to file with my filename so how to remove that number and only filename should remain in script

```
      <?php
     $uploaddir = './'; //Uploading to same directory as PHP file
     $file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
     $uploadFile = $file;
     $randomNumber = rand(0, 99999); 
      $newName = $uploadDir . $randomNumber . $uploadFile;


      if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {
      echo "Temp file uploaded. \r\n";
     } else {
      echo "Temp file not uploaded. \r\n";
      }



        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $newName)) {
       $postsize = ini_get('post_max_size'); //Not necessary, I was using these
       $canupload = ini_get('file_uploads'); //server variables to see what was 
       $tempdir = ini_get('upload_tmp_dir'); //going wrong.
       $maxsize = ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
        echo "http://www.iroboticshowoff.com/dir/{$file}" . "\r\n" . $_FILES['userfile']   ['size'] . "\r\n" . $_FILES['userfile']['type'] ;
       }
    ?>
```

Comment: the code above adds the random number, so why not just remove it? lazy much?

Comment: Lol, how did this question get an upvote? All the posted code?

Answer (score 2):

For security reasons, it can be good to keep the random number though. That way an attacker does not reliably know where an uploaded file will be on the server.

Comment: Agree with this. I actually create subdirectories based on the current timestamp when the file was uploaded, this also alleviates the issue of having 100K files in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the $randomNumber variable from the $newName assignment:

```
// Before
$newName = $uploadDir . $randomNumber . $uploadFile;

// After
$newName = $uploadDir . $uploadFile;
```